# Formal languages and Computability

Tags: computability, formal-languages

Can someone please tell me how would you start proving this?
Thanks 
Prove whether or not language L = {a^(p+qi) : p and q are fixed integer values, and i ≥ 0}
is regular.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Design either a DFA that accepts $L$, a regular grammar that produces $L$, or a regular expression that generates $L$; they’re all pretty straightforward.

Comment: Could you please tell more about this please? I'm still not getting it.

Comment: @user142743: The language is regular. I’ve suggested three ways to prove this: by coming up with a deterministic finite automaton that accepts $L$, a regular grammar that produces $L$, or a regular expression that generates $L$. I included all three of these possibilities because I don’t know which of them you’ve already encountered. I think that the regular expression is easiest to describe in terms of $p$ and $q$, but none of them is difficult to describe.

Comment: could you explain a little bit more on this as well?

Comment: I appreciate it

Comment: @user142743: Which of the three approaches (automata, grammars, regular expressions) have you studied?

Comment: we studied automata

Comment: @user142743: Then you should try to describe a DFA that accepts the words $a^p,a^{p+q},a^{p+2q},a^{p+3q}$, and so on. Each state will have exactly one transition out of it. Since each word in $L$ has $q$ more $a$s than the previous one, you’ll want the DFA to have a ring of $q$ states that it cycles through — but only *after* it has already read that initial string of $p$ a$s. You should find that you have exactly one acceptor state.